# Jquery EasyAutocomplete

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery EasyAutoComplete (http://easyautocomplete.com/).

Here is my Code :

```
<input type="text" name="from" class="form-control" id="autocomplete"/>

<Script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var options = {

    url: function(phrase) {
      return "/home/getCountry";
    },

    getValue: function(element) {
      return element.name;
    },

    ajaxSettings: {
      dataType: "json",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        dataType: "json"
      }
    },

    preparePostData: function(data) {
      data.phrase = $("#autocomplete").val();
      return data;
    },

    requestDelay: 400
  };

  $("#autocomplete").easyAutocomplete(options);
});
</script>
```

It return an 'auto-dropdown' menu just like the example in the websites (http://easyautocomplete.com/examples), but all the words were "Undefined".

Why ?, Any Solutions ?

Comment: can you confirm if you get any response from the url called: `return "/home/getCountry";` does this url produce `json` as a response?

Comment: ah my bad, i found the problem. The json indeed return a response, but not in required format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said,

> *but all the words were "Undefined".*

This seems that your ***easyAutocomplete*** working but problem seems to be at your backend code. The url `/home/getCountry` might not be producing json as a response the way plugin needs.